# How do I find a list I just created? It's not on my site.

Tags: list

I just created a List. Now I can't find it.

Answer (score 4):

you can go to `Site settings > Under Site administration > click on the Site Libraries and Lists.`
Or directly browse to this url( replace with site collection url)

```
https://sitecollection/_layouts/15/mcontent.aspx
```

This page will show all the List and libraries you created.

Comment: That worked. So why can't I find it on my left hand nav bar?

Comment: what sharePoint version you are using? basically there is option when you create a list called navigation, are you want o display this list on the quick launch?

Comment: I'm using SharePoint 2013.

Comment: What is a Quick Launch?

Comment: Left hand side navigation called Quick Launch. You can access the settings for it from Site settings > QUick launch. What template you are using?

Comment: I'm not sure what Template I am using. By Template do you mean the look of the pages I select for my info? Or, do you mean Template that the SharePoint 2013 development tool is using? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Click the Gear icon, click on Site Contents.

Here you can click the ... ellipsis and go to Settings then click Title, description and navigation and tell it to show on the quick launch (left nav).

Answer (score 1):

I also see that the List shows up on as a New List App with the blue box around it under the Sites Contents page. I was used to looking for the List on the left Nav Bar.